# Display percentage column along with Numeric

Tags: excel, charts

I need to show numeric value and its respective percentage in excel 3-d clustered column graph.

Numerics: 30000, 10100, 280000, 560000

Percentage: 20.02%, 34%, 50.12%, 70.28%

Numeric values are so large that its percentage appears just as box.

[image]

I have tried a lot to get this done but, unable to solve.

I also tried solution given here (did not work) http://excelribbon.tips.net/T007888_Numeric_Value_and_Percentage_Value_in_a_Graph_Column.html

Comment: Another possible piece of important information is what version of excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [MS Office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-a-secondary-axis-in-a-chart-233bc85c-b3db-46c4-87f8-4ffafe2a1080) site, secondary vertical axis are not supported in a 3D chart.

You will have to switch to a 2D chart to complete this.

In a 2D chart you can select secondary axis as in the image below:

[image: 2D Column Cluster Chart]

In order to generate the chart in the image above I did the following:

1. Select the range of data (A1:B4)
2. From the insert ribbon select a 2D cluster column chart
3. Select a bar from the series you can see and right click on it and select format data series...
4. From the menu that opens on the right hand side, select the icon that looks like a small bar graph
5. select secondary axis

Comment: So if you tried that as well, what in my picture above is not working?

Comment: can you please show me steps to get this done? Thanks